# vue.js watcher value does not update value in select v-model

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, select, watch

I have a form with a two select boxes.sb1 and sb2. sb2 with a v-model: result.

If I change the value of the first one (sb1) I have to do a some async operation with the value and to obtain a new value that must be placed in the other select box(sb2). For this I've used a watch executing an async fuction, and after I obtain the async value I make  this.result = newValue.
In the console.log is ok, but not in the select box (sb2) that shows nothing
but then, when I unselect a value in the first box (sb1) the value I previously obtained shows up in (sb2)

in general, what is going on here? How can I workaround this?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
           <label for="timezone" >Timezone</label>
            <select
              id="timezone"
              v-model="localValue.timezone"
            >
                <option v-for="(timeZone, index) in arrayTZ()" :key="index" :value="timeZone" :selected="localValue.timezone === timeZone">
                    {{ timeZone }}
                </option>
            </select>
```

and the watcher

```
methods:{
   async getFunction1(id){
     await dispatchingActions
     return objectFromgetFunction1.current
   }
},
watch: {
      async "localValue.ManagerId"(id){
          console.log(id)
          if(id !== null){            
            await this.getFunction1(id)
              this.localValue.timezone = objectFromgetFunction1.current.timezone;
          }
          if(id === null){
              this.localValue.timezone = null
          }
          console.log(this.localValue.timezone)
      },
```

Comment: please share the code

Comment: in sb1 I can select 1 or 2. this is the value i am watching. and in the consol.log works ok. now with the second if only shows null. if I remove this condition I obtain a delay cause this.localValue.timezone is still equal to the value